# Artikel in "Er kennt die zwei Jahre ältere Lisa."

Tags: grammar, adjective, article

> (a) Er kennt die zwei Jahre ältere Lisa.
>
> (b) Er kennt zwei Jahre ältere Lisa.
>
> (c) Er kennt die schöne Lisa.
>
> (d) Er kennt schöne Lisa.

Welche Sätze sind grammatikalisch korrekt? Ich glaube, dass die Sätze (a) und (c) mit dem bestimmten Artikel korrekt sind, ohne Artikel wie in (b) und (d) bin ich mir aber nicht sicher.

Comment: Nur a und c sind korrekt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In geschriebener Sprache wird ein Vorname wie Lisa (ohne weiteres Attribut) ohne Artikel gebraucht.

> 1 Kennst du Lisa?

In der gesprochenen Umgangssprache gebraucht man den Artikel aber doch.

> 2 Kennst du die Lisa?

Hat der Name Attribute (Adjektiv, Relativsatz, etc), muss der Artikel gebraucht werden, weil wir dann von einer näher bestimmten Lisa sprechen.

> 3 Kennst du die kleine Lisa?
>
> 4 Kennst du die Lisa vom Nachbarhaus/, die im Nachbarhaus wohnt?

Comment: Die Benutzung des Artikels in der Umgangssprache scheint mir regional unterschiedlich verbreitet zu sein.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... ist sie definitiv. Das sollte noch in die Antwort, denke ich

Comment: Von regionalen Unterschieden hab ich keine Ahnung. Ich habe hier im Fall von "Kennst du die Lisa?  (Gesprochene Umgangssprache) süddeutschen Gebrauch beschrieben. Das Problem könnte eventuell nur der Sprachatlas beantworten.

Answer (score 2):

Wie du bereits richtig vermutet hast, kann man in diesem Fall die Artikel nicht weglassen, es sind somit nur (a) und (c) korrekt.

Im Allgemeinen gibt es nur die folgenden vier Möglichkeiten:

> 1. Singular, unbestimmt: *Er kennt eine schöne Frau.*
> 2. Singular, bestimmt: *Er kennt die schöne Frau.*
> 3. Plural, unbestimmt: *Er kennt schöne Frauen.*
> 4. Plural, bestimmt: *Er kennt die schönen Frauen.*

Dadurch, dass in deinem Satz mit dem Namen Lisa implizit von einer konkreten, bestimmten Person im Singular die Rede ist, kommt nur der 2. Fall in Frage.

Es gibt jedoch eine Reihe weiterer Fälle, bei denen tatsächlich der bestimmte Artikel weggelassen werden kann, siehe dazu [Nullartikel](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=58).

Answer (score 1):

1. Wird ein Adjektiv vor eine exakt benannte Person (z. B. Lisa) oder vor einen Begriff im Singular gesetzt, muss der Artikel dabei sein. Im Singular kann man den Artikel nur weglassen, wenn jemand konkret mit Namen benannt wird, aber auch dabei kein Adjektiv verwendet wird.

   Richtig:

   > Er kennt die schöne Lisa. Er kennt die schöne Frau. Er kennt Lisa. Er kennt die Frau.

   Falsch:

   > Er kennt schöne Lisa. Er kennt schöne Frau. Er kennt Frau.
2. Im Plural spielt die Verwendung des Adjektivs keine Rolle mehr. Auch der Artikel ist nur noch optional; er kann hierbei hinzugenommen werden, um verstärkt zu betonen, dass es sich eine ganz bestimmte Auswahl aus einer Menge handelt.

Somit sind nur Satz (a) und (c) in der Frage richtig. "2 Jahre ältere" fungiert dabei wie ein einfaches Adjektiv.